# Irish study visa ban based on deception

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-bans

I applied for a study visa in 2018 but I was denied. I deferred my admission to 2019 and reapplied for a study visa again. To my surprise, I was given a 5 year ban for deception. The consulate said I did not indicate that I have been refused a Canadian visa. I have never in my life been to the Canadian embassy, let alone applying. Now my wife has a study visa in the UK. I cannot enter as her dependent because of the ban. I messaged the Canadian embassy through a lawyer to vindicate me but have no reply. What can I do?

Comment: What action did the lawyer advise? What was the reason for the 2018 refusal?

Comment: A Canadian lawyer might be able to make an Access to Information request on your behalf https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/results-by-topic.asp?top=1 Or you can just wait the ban out until your wife finishes her studies and returns from the UK.

Comment: No1,I was denied in 2018 based on language translation document.they didnt even mention enything like canada application in my first refusal

Comment: No2,If i have to wait till my wife finish her study and she is gainfully employed there,my ban would have expired by then,hope i can still join her there?

Comment: Expiry of a ban doesn’t necessarily mean a subsequent visa application would be approved. See https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal re applicability of paragraph 9.8.2 (a) and (c) on entry clearance applications under App FM family members

Comment: I'm unclear about the sequence. Was the ban from Ireland? Did you challenge it at the time?

Comment: The question is indeed unclear. I think the sequence is a 2019 ban from Ireland, which the OP claims was based on a report from Canada that the OP had previously been refused a Canadian visa. The OP claims never to have applied for a Canadian visa, and that therefore the Canadian report of a denied application is erroneous.

Comment: No 1,the ban was from ireland,i consulted an immigration lawyer in Nigeria to help in challenging the ban but uptill now there is no reply from canadian embassy to vindicate me.

Comment: let me make myself clearer,I came down to Nigeria from south korea in 2018 where i was legally staying to proceed my education in ireland.I submitted my application the same year but i was denied based on document translation.there is no time for me to re apply because my school in ireland have resumed.i have to defer my admission till 2019 when i re applied again.i waited for so long before they sent me my document telling me that they have banned me for 5 years because of deception.

Comment: i was told that i have once applied to canadian embassy in 2016and it was not stated in my application that i have applied somewhere before.i have never for once submitted any application to canadian embassy.The time i had interest in applying for canadian express entry,i stopped on the way because i sould not meet up with their requirement.now that my wife got admission into uk.i was told the ban will affect me if i need to visither because ireland and uk work hand in hand.this was a false allegation.nobody to vindicate me.i dont know if there is what i can do to get a ban waiver or ban lift

Comment: What do you mean by "The time I had interest in applying for Canadian express entry, I stopped on the way..." ?  Did you actually begin an application?

Comment: yes i started with the filling of some immigratiom forms online(family and academic backgroun).that is where i stopped

Comment: the form i filled then was canadian immigration assessment form.is that an application?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps Canadian Immigration does consider that form to be an application.

Answer (score 7):

A Canadian Immigration Assessment Test is not an official application. Indeed this is what it says:

> Important: This information is for reference only and no immigration
> decision will be made based on your answers. If you choose to apply,
> your application will be considered by an immigration officer in
> accordance with the Immigration and Refugee Protection Act, without
> regard to any outcome you attain through this questionnaire.

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/come-canada-tool-immigration-express-entry.html

Assuming you’re correct and have never applied for a Canadian visa **and** your identity has not been stolen or compromised by a perpetrator or you don’t share the same name and birthdate etc with some other applicant, the correct thing to do is what your attorney is attempting to do, that is get the Canadian embassy to issue a formal correspondence that you have never previously done so.

Waiting out the ban is not the correct course of action because as it was pointed out to you, expiry of a ban doesn’t necessarily mean a subsequent visa application would be approved. It is in your best interest to address this because the denial of your Irish visa can also lead denial of application for other countries in a destructive cycle all related to the incorrect ban because you allegedly applied for a Canadian visa previously.